# COUNTIF in Google Sheets excluding columns with given header

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, countif

In the following Sheet:

[image]

I'm trying to count the instances of the looked-up value `IDL` but only in the `Scheduled` columns, not the `Accomplished` ones.

Is there anyway I can feed a `FILTER` to a `COUNTIF` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=COUNTIF(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:I), "select * where Col1='Scheduled'"),"=IDL")
```

[image]

or less dynamic:

```
=COUNTIF(QUERY(A2:I, "select A,C,E,G"), "=IDL")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. Can A,C,E, etc. be dynamic? Like "All columns starting from C skipping 1" or "All columns that have a first row value of Scheduled"?

Comment: I tried that but it actually doesn't work; the result suddenly becomes 0.

Comment: instead Col1='Scheduled'" try Col1 matches 'Scheduled'" or Col1 contains 'Scheduled'"

Comment: also you can try: =COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:I), "select * where Col1='Scheduled'"))),"=IDL")